# Are there two subsets $A, B$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $\bar A = \bar B$, $A\subset B$; however, $A^a\ne B^a$.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Are there two subsets $A, B$ of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology such that $\bar A  = \bar B$, $A\subset  B$; however, $A^a\ne B^a$?

Here $A^a$ means the set of all limit points of $A$.

Comment: what do you mean by A^a ?

Comment: I tried to format! D: What I mean is the set of limit points of A.

Comment: Hmm, let me work that out, Henning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such sets. Since $A\subseteq B$ it follows $A^a\subseteq B^a$. We need to prove that $B^a\subseteq A^a$. Suppose the contrary, that there is some $p\in B^a\setminus A^a$. Take a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ that does not intersect $A$ (except possibly at $p$). But $U$ must intersect $B$ in points other than $p$, say a point $q$. But then $q\in \bar B\setminus\bar A$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, Mirko. I am working this out, trying to understand each step!