# Find two subsets $A$, $B$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $A^{a} = B^{a}$, $A\subset B$ but $\bar{A}\neq \bar{B}$.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Find two subsets $A$, $B$ of the real numbers with the usual topology such that $A^{a} = B^{a}$, $A\subset B$ but $\bar{A}\neq \bar{B}$.

We know that the closure of $A$ is the subset of the closure of $B$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Notation: $A^a$ means the set of limit points of $A$.

Comment: What is $A^a$? Interior?

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)

Comment: It is the set of limit of points of A - it is a notation found in Rudin, if that helps.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that is a similar question. I think it is different, though.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: see a related question and answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000715/are-there-two-subsets-a-b-of-the-real-numbers-with-the-usual-topology-such-that/1000720#1000720

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Pick some non-closed set $B$.  To get $A$, remove some points of $B$ that don't affect the set of limit points.

**Hint 2**: What's the simplest example of a non-closed set that you can think of?

Comment: The simplest non-closed set that I can think of (0,1). The complement of (0,1) is (-infinity,0] union [1, infinity).

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't a very good hint.  $(0,1) $ is complicated for this problem because it has so many limit points. Can you think of a set with only one limit point?

Comment: How about {1/n∣ n∈N}? I think the limit point is 0.

Comment: You could use that for $B$, but can you find a proper subset of $B$ with the same limit point?